# Proof that the sum of the limits is the limit of the sum not subtracting infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I have looked in several places, and with very slight variations, every time the proof does something like this: $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ and later on $|x-a|$. But when $a$ is the infinity, I'm getting the eerie feeling that something has gone terribly wrong here. I mean, $a$ in this formula isn't necessary a number, how is it OK to subtract it from anything?

Anyways, I'm just looking for a proof which follows a different procedure, where this manipulation isn't required.

Comment: Hint: what is the definition for the limit for $x\to +\infty$?

Comment: @Cla I have no idea... is there one?

Comment: How would we be able to work with it if it doesn't have a definition?

Comment: If you have problems with it, you should know that when calculus was originally developed you just substituted infinity in. Now we use limits, and its been proven you can just sub x for infinity, with some precautions. So use the limit definition even though infinity isn't supposed to be a number, or just sub in infinity and be accused of not having formalism. Either one works.

Comment: @Henrik what I mean is is there anything special, that's not a part of the definition of limits in general? Is this a reference to being able to find a value smaller than the difference between the value the limit approaches to and some arbitrary chosen value? (That's not exclusive to infinity).

Comment: @Zach466920 I'm reading a book (although in the very beginning just yet) which approaches calculus through hyperreals, do you think it might give a better definition? (the book is "Mathematical Background:
Foundations of Infinitesimal Calculus").

Comment: @wvxvw in brief, yes. However it will take a fairly intuitive concept and make it somewhat incomprehensible. On the plus side, approaching infinity from the right will make sense again.

Comment: @Zach466920 thanks. I skimmed further through the book and I see nowhere does it mention $x \to \infty$, instead it uses $\delta x \to 0$. I didn't yet find the place where the authors explain this, but it seems like there's a way of avoiding the mention of infinity in this context altogether.

Comment: @wvxvw Oh, that's the change in x which is an analogue for the plus and minus on the limit, for minus you approach from the left, and for plus you approach from the right. In a somewhat hand wavy fashion, to approach 2 from the right you do it by having 2+$\delta x$ where the add on is the approach from the right in a traditional limit. As it goes to zero you approach 2. In infinitesimal calculus, you never go to 0 but rather $\epsilon$ a value greater than zero but less than all other  positive real numbers. Edit: you might be able to go to 0, but then you're out of my depth.